# I have to find the marginal pmf's $f_X$, $f_Y$ and $f_{X+Y}$ of $X+Y$.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

I have to find $D > 0$ such that $f(x, y)$ = $D$($\frac{1}{x+y−1}$$+$ $\frac{1}{x+y+1}$ $−$ $\frac{2}{x+y}$) is the joint pmf $f_{X,Y} (x, y)$ of a random vector $(X,Y)$ in 
{$1,2,..$}$^2$. And then I have to find the marginal pmf's $f_X$, $f_Y$ and $f_{X+Y}$ of $X+Y$.

My attempt: First I tried to find $D$

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}$$\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}$ $D$($\frac{1}{x+y−1}$$+$ $\frac{1}{x+y+1}$ $−$ $\frac{2}{x+y}$) = $1$

D$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}$ $\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}$($\frac{2}{(x+y−1)(x+y+1)(x+y)})$ = $1$

$D$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac{1}{x^2+x}$= $1$

$D$ = $1$

Then:

$f_X(x)$ = $\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}$$D$($\frac{2}{(x+y−1)(x+y+1)(x+y)})$

$f_X(x)$ = $\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}$$\frac{2}{(x+y−1)(x+y+1)(x+y)}$

$f_X(x)$ = $\frac{1}{x^2+x}$

Then:

$f_Y(y)$ = $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}$$D$($\frac{2}{(x+y−1)(x+y+1)(x+y)})$

$f_Y(y)$ = $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}$$\frac{2}{(x+y−1)(x+y+1)(x+y)}$

$f_Y(y)$ = $\frac{1}{y^2+y}$

For $f_{X+Y}$ I was thinking of the following:

Set $U=X$ and $V=X+Y$, then use the change of variables theorem, note that:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial X} & \frac{\partial U}{\partial Y} \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial X} & \frac{\partial V}{\partial Y} 
\end{pmatrix}$
= $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant one. Hence,

$f_{U,V}$ = $f_{X,Y}(x(u,v),y(u,v))$ = $\frac{2}{(x+y−1)(x+y+1)(x+y)}$ = $\frac{2}{(u+v-u-1)(u+v-u+1)(u+v-u)}$ = $\frac{2}{(v-1)(v+1)v}$ by the change of variables

Now we get via $f_V$

$f_V(v)$ = $\sum_{v=2}^{\infty}$ $\frac{2}{(v-1)(v+1)v}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

Now I have to calculate the conditional pmf's $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

I know that we have to use:

$f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ = $P(X=x|Y=y)$ = $\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(Y=Y)}$

I am not sure if the above answers are correct.

So any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $D$ you are looking for is supposed to be a constant, not depend on $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Then I am not sure where it goes wrong, any help would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct concerning $D$, $f_X$ and $f_Y$.

For finding $f_{X+Y}$ realize that for $n=2,3,\dots$ we have:

$P\left(X+Y=n\right)=\sum_{x+y=n}\left[\frac{1}{x+y-1}+\frac{1}{x+y+1}-\frac{2}{x+y}\right]=\left(n-1\right)\left[\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{2}{n}\right]$

Comment: So is that the final answer? because the part within the [...] brackets is equal to $\frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)n}$ and that I already calculated

Comment: Where did I do something wrong in my computation? Can you explicitly show me please?

Comment: Leading to $f_{X+Y}(n)=2(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1})$ for $n=2,3,\dots$. I am not really familiar with your way of finding it by means of determinants. IMV that is far-fetched and/or cumbersome. I feel reluctant to find mistakes because I am not familiar with your method.

Comment: Ok, yeah I saw my way of calculating using the determinant in past exams . But is there a way you can give me a more extensive answer? I try to understand your way of thinking. Or is this the whole answer already?

Comment: Do you understand that e.g. $f_{X+Y}(5)=f_{X,Y}(1,4)+f_{X,Y}(2,3)+f_{X,Y}(3,2)+f_{X,Y}(4,1)$? Actually that's all there is to it. Fortunately we have $f_{X,Y}(1,4)=f_{X,Y}(2,3)=f_{X,Y}(3,2)=f_{X,Y}(4,1)$ in this matter so you can also write it as $4f_{X,Y}(1,4)$. This works not only for $n=5$ but for every $n\geq2$. You already found $D,f_X,f_Y$. This gives you $f_{X+Y}$ so things are complete now.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Now I have to determine the conditional  pmf's $f_{X|Y}$ and $f_{Y|X}$. I will edit the question and is there a way you can also help me with that?

Comment: I would advice you to pose that as *another* question, eventually with a link to this question.

Comment: Okay, I shall post it as another question

Comment: I posted it as a new question!