# I have to find the conditional pmf's $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$f(x, y)$ = ($\frac{1}{x+y−1}$$+$ $\frac{1}{x+y+1}$ $−$ $\frac{2}{x+y}$)

I have to find the conditional pmf's $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

I know we can use the following formula, but I do not know how to apply it:

$f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ = $P(X=x|Y=y)$ = $\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ = $\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(X=x)}$.

After this, I have to show that X, Y are independent.

Any help would be grateful Thanks in advance.

I already started with some preliminaries in another question. It was better to post this as a new question.

[I have to find the marginal pmf's $f_X$, $f_Y$ and $f_{X+Y}$ of $X+Y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705536/i-have-to-find-the-marginal-pmfs-f-x-f-y-and-f-xy-of-xy/3705705?noredirect=1#comment7615697_3705705)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already know that: $$f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{x+y-1}+\frac{1}{x+y+1}-\frac{2}{x+y}\tag1$$

In your former question you found out that: $$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{y^{2}+y}\tag2$$

So you can get an expression for: $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\tag3$$by substituting $(1)$ and $(2)$ in $(3)$.

Observe that in $(3)$ the $y$ is fixed and the $x$ is variable. Another notation for it (making that fact more clear) is: $$f_{Y=y}(x)$$

Similar story for $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have already found that:$$\begin{align}\sum_{y=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac 1{x+y-1}-\dfrac 2{x+y}+\dfrac{1}{x+y+1}\right)&=\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{2}{x+1}+\dfrac{1}{x+2}\right)+\left(\dfrac 1{x+1}-\dfrac{2}{x+2}+\dfrac 1{x+3}\right)+\cdots\\&=\dfrac 1 x-\dfrac 1{x+1}\\&=\dfrac 1{x^2+x}\\[3ex] \sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac 1x-\dfrac 1{x+1}\right)&=1\end{align}$$

So giving you that:$$\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\left(\dfrac{1}{x+y-1}-\dfrac 2{x+y}+\dfrac 1{x+y+1}\right)\mathbf 1_{x\in\Bbb N^+,y\in\Bbb N^+}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 2{(x+y-1)(x+y)(x+y+1)}\mathbf 1_{\langle x,y\rangle\in(\Bbb N^+)^2}\\[1ex]f_X(x)&=\left(\dfrac 1x-\dfrac 1{x+1}\right)\mathbf 1_{x\in\Bbb N^+}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 1{x^2+x}\mathbf 1_{x\in\Bbb N^+}\\[2ex]f_Y(y)&=\left(\dfrac 1y-\dfrac 1{y+1}\right)\mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb N^+}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 1{y^2+y}\mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb N^+}\end{align}$$

Then by definition $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\dfrac{y^2+y}{(x+y-1)(x+y)(x+y+1)}\mathbf 1_{\langle x,y\rangle\in(\Bbb N^+)^2}$$

---

Similarly

$$\begin{align}f_{X+Y}(z)&=\sum_{y=1}^{z-1} f_{X,Y}(z-y, y)\\[1ex]&=\sum_{y=1}^{z-1}\left(\dfrac 2{(z-1)z(z+1)}\right)~\mathbf 1_{z\in\Bbb N\cap[2..\infty)}\\[2ex]&\vdots\end{align}$$